# How to decide Image thumbnail size for any Android application

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, gpu, rendering

Usecase:

In music player app,
 how to decide ?

1. Best resolution for image displayed in list as part of thumbnail.
2. After clicking on list, resolution of detailed image in detail page.

Is this always depend on business usecase or any standard to follow for best performance to reduce GPU rendering